# SQL Function Like

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem with SQL on Codeigniter. 
I would like to see the names of the clients who started with the letter A.. from A to C .. so A-B-C

I write this code :

```
    if ((isset($filtri["name_from"])) && ($filtri["name_from"])) :
        $this->db->where("clienti.nome LIKE ",$filtri["name_from"]."%");
    endif;  
    if ((isset($filtri["name_to"])) && ($filtri["name_to"])) :

        for($i = $filtri["name_from"]++; $i <= $filtri["name_to"]; $i++){

            $this->db->or_where("clienti.nome LIKE ",$i."%");
        }

    endif;
```

But doesn't work when i use another Filter... why ?

Comment: Since you're using Query Builder, why not use the correct methods for `like` instead of hacking your way into something that may or may not work? You should look into `$this->db->like()` syntax [HERE](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs (https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) uses a different approach:

> If you want to control where the wildcard (%) is placed, you can use an optional third argument. Your options are ‘before’, ‘after’, ‘none’ and ‘both’ (which is the default).

```
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'before');  // Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE '%match' ESCAPE '!'
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'after');   // Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE 'match%' ESCAPE '!'
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'none');    // Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE 'match' ESCAPE '!'
$this->db->like('title', 'match', 'both');    // Produces: WHERE `title` LIKE '%match%' ESCAPE '!'
```

So, you can try:

```
if ((isset($filtri["name_from"])) && ($filtri["name_from"])) :
    $this->db->like("clienti.nome",$filtri["name_from"],"after");
endif;  
if ((isset($filtri["name_to"])) && ($filtri["name_to"])) :

    for($i = $filtri["name_from"]++; $i <= $filtri["name_to"]; $i++){

        $this->db->or_like("clienti.nome",$i,"after");
    }

endif;
```

Comment: Ok but when i use another filter .. like Date , Filter["name_from"] print all names.

Comment: I can't see your entire code, only the part that you wrote here. For the problem you asked for, this is the right solution. You may wan't to refactor your form or create a new question here on stackoverflow with your new question.